# How did the Egyptians who didn't fear Hashem have animals?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, animals, plagues-makkos, va-eira

To address the question of how the Egyptians had any animals after Dever, Rashi (9:10) quotes the Mechilta

> ואם תאמר מאין היו להם הבהמות והלא כבר נאמר (פסוק ו) וימת כל מקנה מצרים, אלא לא נגזרה גזרה אלא על אותן שבשדות בלבד, שנאמר (פסוק ג) במקנך אשר בשדה והירא את דבר ה' הניסה את מקנהו אל הבתים.
>
> How did they have animals, after it already said "And all the Egyptian animals died"?  Rather the decree was only on the ones in the fields, as the pasuk says "on your animals in the field", and the ones who feared Hashem brought his animals into the house.

That explains how there were animals susceptible to Shechin, how there were animals to move inside during Barad, and how there were horses to pull the chariots to the Yam Suf.  But the pasuk (9:21) says explicitly that there were also Egyptians who didn't fear Hashem and who left their animals in the fields during Barad.

Where did *they* get animals from?  If they feared Hashem enough to move their animals inside based on a drasha in Hashem's words, then why didn't they do the same when He told them to do so explicitly?

Answer (score 2):

As I explain in [Contradiction between Shemos 9:6 and 9:20-21?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76784/contradiction-between-shemos-96-and-920-21/76786#76786) they could have purchased animals from those people who still had them, from nonEgyptians, or from outside the borders of Egypt. Thus, they could have gotten new animals to replace the ones that died during דבר and then left them out again during ברד. Additionally, some might have had their animals inside for other reasons than having listened to Moshe and taken heed of his warning.

Comment: It seems from Rashi in Beshalach that there wasn't too much buying and selling going on at that time.  If bad Egyptians bought animals from good Egyptians he would have no proof that כשר שבמצרים הרוג (maybe the good ones didn't contribute directly).